# Does Tizen OS support AngularJS 2?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

Does **Tizen OS** support **AngularJS 2**?

Comment: you'll find more info about Angular 2 here:
https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/introduction-angular-2-tizen

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Tizen does support angular 2.

> Throughout the last years **AngularJS** was considered probably the most
>   popular JavaScript framework around. It is very versatile and was used
>   all over the planet in many industries to create stunning web
>   applications. But as time passed, we got information about the new
>   Angular 2 coming our way. And yes, if you look on the chart below
>   (fig.1) the interest about Angular 2**** has increased and will get even
>   higher in the upcoming future. That is why we have dedicated this
>   article to introduce Tizen developers to **Angular 2**. The current
>   version of the framework, while writing this article, is **rc.5**. In this
>   article we will show you how to setup a simple Angular 2 project.

https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/introduction-angular-2-tizen

Comment: This is essentially a link only answer, consider copying some of relevant the content from the link to here to show how it answers the question in case the link ever dies (likely)

Comment: @Mauro, This answer clearly answers the question (which is a yes/no question) and provides a link to support that answer. It is not link only.

Comment: The standard is to reference the relevant section by copying it to the asnwer (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) as the link will inevitably be killed off, you'll see from the edited answer that it provides the relevant information without having to navigate away from SO and also provides the link to reference the content.

Comment: @Mauro, The answer can be improved by providing more detail. However, you called this a link-only answer, which is a very specific thing (particularly in a review queue/flagging context). A link-only answer does not *actually* answer the question, without clicking the link. Such answers are not considered answers and can/should be flagged as NAA. This answer, even in it's original form, provided an actual answer to the question, without the need to click the link. I'm not saying that either the question or answer were/are good, but that is an issue for down-votes, not NAA flags/deleting.

Comment: @makyen i didnt flag it as naa nor did i down vote it. I still feel it was essentially a link only answer as it didnt specifically call out the references and have had my own answers flagged as such in the past. Lets leave it as such.